# Getting all child nodes of a node list with XML::LibXML

Tags: xml, perl

I have the following XML file

```xml
<root>
  <test name="test1">
    <node name="node1">
    </node>
    <child type="" line="321" name="">
      <grandChild name="WM">
        ....
      </grandChild>
    </child>
  </test>
  <test name="test2">
    <node name="node2">
    </node>
    <child type="" line="123" name="">
      <grandChild name="WM">
        ....
      </grandChild>
    </child>
  </test>
</root>
```

I want to access some of the nodes if a condition holds, but I am failing to get the `<grandChild>` child elements.

My Perl code is as follows

```perl
my $xml = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new();

my $xpc = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new();
$xpc->registerNs(sr => 'http://www.froglogic.com/XML2');

my $tree         = $parser->parse_file($xmlFile);
my $nodes        = $xml->findnodes("//sr:root/sr:test[$attribute]", $tree);
my $childTagName = 'child';

foreach my $node ( $nodes->get_nodelist ) {

    my $childNodes = $node->getChildNodes();

    foreach my $childNode ( $childNodes->get_nodelist ) {

        if ( $childNode->getName() eq $childTagName ) {

            my $newresults = $childNode->findnodes('//child');
        }
    }
}
```

Of course the main part of it is deleted to simplify my question.

I should mention that `$attribute` is the test names (test1, test2, ....).

Would you please let me know why I could not get grandchild in `$newresults` and it is always empty when I am printing to the command console.

Comment: It's not clear what is in `$attribute`. Is it a string with all the values separated by commas `test1,test2` or does it somehow have just one of these values at a time using code you haven't shown? Either way, your XPath expression `//sr:root/sr:test[$attribute]` is wrong, and should be like `/sr:root/sr:test[@name="test1"]` etc. (Why search everywhere in the data for an `<sr:root>` element when it's right at the top?)

Comment: @Borodin As I have written in my explanation it is the attribute `name` of test nodes, i.e. in `<test name="test1">` is for example  `test1`.

Comment: And as I said, what you wrote isn't clear. You say that `$attribute` is `(test1, test2, ....)`, but does that include the parentheses and the dots? Either way, stuffing that into an XPath predicate doesn't make sense. Please show the code that defines `$attribute` and some examples of its value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code isn't runnable. Where has `$attribute` come from? Also, you don't show the definition of the `sr` namespace in the XML, so it's hard to guess what the problem is, but my guess is the `child` also belongs to the namespace. If that's the case, you have to use the prefix for it, too, and use the XPath context to search for it. Also, use XPath to specify the conditions instead of iterating over childnodes:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

use XML::LibXML;

my $tree = 'XML::LibXML'->load_xml(IO => *DATA);
my $xpc = 'XML::LibXML::XPathContext'->new($tree);
$xpc->registerNs(sr => 'http://sr');

my $attribute = '@name';
my $test_nodes = $xpc->findnodes("/sr:root/sr:test[$attribute]");
for my $test_node (@$test_nodes) {
    for my $child_node ($xpc->findnodes('sr:child', $test_node)) {
        my $newresults = $xpc->findnodes('sr:grandChild', $child_node);
        say join ' ',
            $test_node->{name},
            $child_node->{line},
            $_->{name}
            for @$newresults;
    }
}

__DATA__
<root xmlns='http://sr'>
    <test name="test1">
        <node name="node1">

        </node>
        <child type="" line="321" name="">
            <grandChild name="WM">
                ....
            </grandChild>
        </child>

    </test>
    <test name="test2">
        <node name="node2">

        </node>
        <child type="" line="123" name="">
            <grandChild name="WM">
                ....
            </grandChild>
        </child>
    </test>
</root>
```

Comment: please see my revised version. I hope it is clear now! Thanks for your answer.
But What I need is to use `->get_nodelist`. Because I want to go through each node one by one, rather than using `findnodes` in first place.

Comment: @Royeh: Too late :-) But you should be able to get the exact solution from my answer, anyway. Note that I slightly improved it.

Comment: @Royeh: The code for the `get_nodelist` method is exactly `@$test_nodes`. The two are exactly equivalent.